# ZeroMQ example in C won't compile; could the official documentation be wrong?

Tags: c, zeromq

There is a basic example provided at the official ZeroMQ site **[here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)** (scroll down to the section "Ask and Ye Shall Receive"):

```
// Hello World server

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    // Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new (); // LINE NUMBER 9
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0); // LINE NUMBER 15
        printf ("Received Hello\n");
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0); // LINE NUMBER 17
        sleep (1); // Do some 'work'
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I installed ZeroMQ from the standard repositories.  But when I attempt to compile the example above, I get the following errors:

```
./test.c: In function ‘main’:
./test.c:9:21: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
./test.c:15:9: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zmq_recv’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/zmq.h:228:16: note: expected ‘struct zmq_msg_t *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
./test.c:15:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘zmq_recv’
/usr/include/zmq.h:228:16: note: declared here
./test.c:17:9: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘zmq_send’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/zmq.h:227:16: note: expected ‘struct zmq_msg_t *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
./test.c:17:9: error: too many arguments to function ‘zmq_send’
/usr/include/zmq.h:227:16: note: declared here
```

So I looked up the definition of `zmq_recv` and `zmq_send` in `/usr/include/zmq.h` and found that the compiler is indeed telling the truth.  The following are the signatures:

```
int zmq_bind (void *s, const char *addr);
int zmq_send (void *s, zmq_msg_t *msg, int flags);
int zmq_recv (void *s, zmq_msg_t *msg, int flags);
```

So, am I correct in thinking the documentation at the site is incorrect (or perhaps outdated)?  Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: so first of all make sure you have the correct versions - the ones from the default repo may not be right for the docs you're looking at.  Secondly are you using the correct flags?

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf, yes indeed.  I looked at the source file, and it appears that repositories of `Ubuntu 12.04` only have `version 2.1.11`.  The tutorial assumes that the version number is at least `3.2`.  Silly of me; I just kind of assumed that a major distribution like Ubuntu would have a reasonably up-to-date version.

Answer (score 3):

This will work. You are getting this issue because you don't have the development package. I have verified this on ubuntu.

```
#sudo apt-get install libzmq3-dev
#gcc  test.c -o Zmserver.out -lzmq
```